# Not wrapping the 'value' in the input box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this simple code:

```
<input type="text" value="Some Extremely Really Long Word" />
```

How do I make sure the value (in this case 'Some Extremely Really Long Word') shows up completely (ie. is not clipped).

I tried to apply the style: overflow:visible and display:nowrap but it didn't work.

I don't want to apply a style like: width: 200px because I don't know how long the words will be.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TfKbp/3/

Comment: you may need to use textarea. check this [jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/gLhCk/5/)

Comment: What if you used Javascript to find out the length of the word, and then applied that length to the text box?

Comment: I also tried all CSS tricks I know, no success: http://jsfiddle.net/TfKbp/6/

Answer (score 3):

I've used this in the past to dynamically expand the width of a text `INPUT` to the width of its contents.  Basically, you create a `SPAN` with the exact same font family, font size, etc. and use the `keypress` event to add the characters, measure its size, and resize the `INPUT`.

***EDIT 1***

To dynamically size the text box for its initial value requires just a little more code...

**HTML**

```
<input id="txtLong" type="text" value="What does the fox say? Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding! Gering-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding! Gering-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding! What the fox say?" />
<span id="spanLong" style="display: none;"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var txtLong = $("#txtLong");
var spanLong = $("#spanLong");

spanLong.text(txtLong.val());
txtLong.css("width", spanLong.width());

txtLong.keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
        var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode | e.charCode);
        spanLong.text(txtLong.val() + char);
        txtLong.css("width", spanLong.width());
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
input, span {
    padding: 2px 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

**[New and Improved Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkX3m/2/)**

---

***EDIT 2***

Since you're looking for a way to select text by clicking on it, I thought I'd also point out that you don't necessarily need an `INPUT` to do that. Check out **[this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/KcX6A/1507/)**. And as an added bonus, it doesn't use JQuery. I know you were kinda opposed to that.

---

***EDIT 3***

I found a way to simply resize a textbox to the width of its initial value using only plain JavaScript by adapting [this blog post](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/measuring-the-length-of-a-string-in-pixels-using-javascript/).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtLong" value="Some very long text that all needs to show"/>
<span id="ruler"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
String.prototype.visualLength = function()
{
    var ruler = document.getElementById("ruler");
    ruler.innerHTML = this;
    return ruler.offsetWidth;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var txtLong = document.getElementById("txtLong");
    var width = txtLong.value.visualLength();
    txtLong.setAttribute("style", "width:" + width + "px");
}
```

**CSS**

```
#ruler {
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#txtLong, #ruler {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5Vq5/)**

Comment: The problem is - the value in the input is fixed, ie. there is no typing involved..

Comment: Then may I ask why you're using an `INPUT` if there's no typing involved? Wouldn't a `SPAN` or a `DIV` fit your needs better?

Comment: Because user is supposed to copy the text, like in this code (imagine it's a coupon code):

<input onclick="this.select();" type="text" value="Some loong coupon code">

Comment: That's a good reason. I've edited my answer to dynamically resize for an initial value.

Comment: Ok.. I was hoping it could be done in HTML5/CSS3 (easy way) somehow, but if not then it's the best effort worth a useful answer.

Comment: Since you want to select text when it's clicked, I updated my answer to include a JSFiddle that doesn't use an `INPUT` and doesn't rely on JQuery.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a solution that uses a textbox and plain Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is no declarative way (that I know of) to do this, but it is fairly easy to do using jQuery. What you essentially need to do is make a second element (not an `input`) that contains all the same styling as the `input`. Then measure the width of the second element, and set width of the `input` to that new width.

Here's how you'd do that:

HTML:

```
<input type='text' value='Some Extremely Really Long Word' id='my-input' />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {\

    var $input = $('#my-input'),
        $clone = $('<div></div>');

    $clone.html($input.val());
    $clone.css({
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        font: $input.css('font'),
        paddingLeft: $input.css('padding-left'),
        paddingRight: $input.css('padding-right')
    });
    $clone.appendTo($('body'));
    $input.css({
        width: $clone.width();
    });
    $clone.remove();

})
```

Comment: jquery would be the last option.. Hard to use jQuery for this little thing only : |.

Comment: You can do it all without JQuery, but it will take a lot more effort. Why reinvent the wheel when a well-tested 91.4K file can make it so simple? I'm sure you will find other uses for it in your site as well.